# Getting 500 error while uploading image from next js 13 to s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, next.js, frontend

In next 13, in the app folder i have created an api folder and inside that there is route.js file. The code for route.js is

```js
import { s3 } from "@/app/lib/s3";


export const POST= async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(405).json({ message: "Method not allowed" });
  }



  try {
    // retrieve the data
    const { name, type } = req.body;


    const params = {
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: name,
      // Body: body,
      ContentType: type,
    };

    const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise("putObject", params);
    return res.status(200).json({ url });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

inside app folder, I have lib/s3. Here is the code for s3.js

```js
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

export const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});
```

This function runs on onClick event when user uploads the image.

```js
   const [imageFile, setImageFile] = useState(null);

 
 const handleSaveClick = async () => {
    setIsEditing(false);
    const params = {
      file: imageFile,
    };

    try {
      const resp = await upload(params);
      setProfileSrc(resp);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        " ~ file: ProfileInformation.js:66 ~ handleSaveClick ~ error:",
        error
      );
    }
    // You can also update the imageURL state if needed
  };


//i am setting image like this which i beleive is working fine

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    // Handle image change logic here
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setImageFile(file);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      setImageURL(event.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
```

This is the helper upload function

```js
export const upload = async (file) => {
  const dirName = 'the365nft/';
  const fileName = dirName ? dirName + file.file.name : file.file.name;
  try {
    console.log('its in try here upload')
    const response = await axios.post("/api/s3", {
      name: fileName,
      type: file.file.type,
    });
    console.log(" ~ file: APi.js:24 ~ upload ~ response:", response)

    const { url } = response.data;
    console.log(" ~ file: APi.js:26 ~ upload ~ url:", url)

    await axios.put(url, file.file, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": file.file.type,
      },
    });
    console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_S3_URL,'env')
    return `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_S3_URL}/${fileName}`;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Whenever I hit the api, I get 500 error in the console saying that internal server error